# Android: Index Out Of Bound Exception in ArrayList

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using Array Adapter to display Array list in List View. I can *Add* and *delete* items. Suppose If there is no *item* in List view, If I select *delete* its showing Index out of Bind Exception. What I required is it should show toast like "There is no item to delete".Clarify me Experts!! And my code is below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    al = new ArrayList<String>();
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    bAdd.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str1 = et1.getText().toString();
            if (str1.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Enter Item first!!", 0).show();
            } else {
                al.add(0, str1);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                et1.setText("");
            }

        }
    });
    bDel.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (arg0 == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Nothing to delete", 0).show();
            } else {
                al.remove(0);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the size of `al` list before you delete it:

```
        if (arg0 == null || al.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Nothing to delete", 0).show();
        } else {
            al.remove(0);
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: I might also suggest disabling the Delete button when there's nothing in the list instead of showing a `Toast`. It's somewhat confusing to have a usable Delete button on the screen when the list is empty.

Comment: use a1.isEmpty() instead of a1.size() == 0

Comment: @Geobits Suppose If I want to replace 'Item 1' by new 'Item y'(Update) from EditText What's the procedure to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Set validation on array, see below

```
bDel.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (arg0 == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Nothing to delete", 0).show();
        } else {
            if(al.size == 0){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "There is no item to delete", 0).show();
               return;
             }
            al.remove(0);
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```